# Store data in variable specific to request in node express js

Tags: node.js, express, var

I want to store data in variable but it should be specific to user.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var storedata='';

app.get('/:accountcode', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  storedata=req.params.accountcode;
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('initialize', function(msg){
    console.log(storedata); //Here all users data can be seen.
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Now I access this link for different accountcode from different browser, I can see that storedata variable is global and it can is being maintained and not like maintained differently for different users.
How to declare variable so that it is not replaced and it remain specific to user only. To solve issue I generated one unique id on `app.get` and passed it to client side and on request to server passing that id so variable is maintained with different id so it remains unique for all users like.

```
storedata[uniqid]=req.params.accountcode
```

and access it using this `uniqid` only. It works but on all request i can see all id data, it would be great if it can be maintained differently only.

Comment: What do you mean by "It works but on all request i can see all id data , it would be great if it can be maintained differently only."

Comment: suppose on user requested so for account code 1 so value will be storedata["123364887dsdr"]=1;

and another user storedata["3648gfha87dsdr"]=2;
so when i console i can see {"123364887dsdr"=>1,"3648gfha87dsdr"=>2}

i don't want this for user 1 variable value should be  {"123364887dsdr"=>1} and 2 {"3648gfha87dsdr"=>2} but getting both data. and for single variable it gets replaces which should not be like that.

Comment: More preferred is to store data in database not in variable because that can create problem, In future you need to use the `clustering` or may be need to run `nodejs` in  multiple process.

Comment: I already have data in my database but I don't want to get it again and again from database instead want to store it so that it can be easily accessible. I am new to node , is this the way node works not any way to declare variable in a way it is specific to user connection ?

Comment: In that case, Redis will be a better solution.

Comment: Well, if you still want to use this way, you can access the value using storedata[uniqid].

Comment: Yes , but in that case data will be stored in memory and it can create a problem. Redis is the solution but still if this variables can work  like variables work in client side javascript it would be great.